# bitget function for array input and array bit selection

Tags: matlab

I can do this

```
bitget(564,16:-1:1,'int16')
```

to get all 16 bits from the int16 representation of 564. Or do

```
bitget([564; 1235] ,3,'int16')
```

to get the 3rd bits from the int16 representations of 564,1235 (output is a 2x1 vector)

unfortunately I seem to run into an error with

```
bitget([564; 1235] ,16:-1:1,'int16')
```

Any suggestions (besides looping over the elements either the 1st or 2nd argument)?

Comment: Use `de2bi`: `de2bi([564; 1235],16,'left-msb')`?

Comment: @Divakar . Thanks for the idea, should work for my intentions